# Howto Test delete method in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a method in controller that I would like to test

```
public function destroy(Instrument $instrument)
{
    $instrument->delete();

    flash()->success('Instrument Deleted Successfully!');

    return Redirect::route('instrument.index');
}
```

If I am to test controller manually method works fine.

However, I have been trying to test this without much luck...
btw, this method is accessed via DELETE method.

Below are some example of calls that I have tried:

```
$this->action('DELETE', 'InstrumentController@destroy', ['id' => 19]);
```

And this..

```
$this->delete('/instrument/destroy/19');
```

I was trying to test using $this->visit() but when you click on delete button a bootstrap toolkit appears, because its not preloaded in the dom i am unable to test using $this->visit()...

If some one could help out, would be great

Comment: what does your route look like ? `Route::delete or Route::resource` ? I think these are post requests and require a csfr token. You may find this helpful: http://davejustdave.com/2015/02/08/laravel-5-unit-testing-with-csrf-protection/

Comment: Like I say I think the CSFR token is your issue with testing the article linked above should help you out.

Comment: I am not sure if it's related to CSFR token, because destroy method requires an $id element, not $request.. but i will try this out and see.

Answer (score 2):

You can test it like this:

```
public function testDelete()
{
    $response = $this->call('DELETE', 'instrument/19');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

and in case you need to provide the csrf token just pass it in an array as the third argument to the `call` method

```
['_token' => csrf_token()]
```

Comment: I had a go, and after reading article that futureweb posted I have disabled middleware and everything worked. I have also noticed that csrf_token() returns null.. it doesn't seem to be set for some reason?

$this->withoutMiddleware();
        $response = $this->call('DELETE', '/instrument/20');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->notSeeInDatabase('instrument', ['deleted_at' => null, 'id' => 20]);